# webpack-dev-server does not watch for my file changes

Tags: npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

When I change my files while webpack-dev-server is running, the bundle's files are not updated.
Here are my webpack.config.js and package.json files, as you can see from my npm script, I've solved running `webpack watch` and `webpack-dev-server` in the same command (`npm run watch &  webpack-dev-server --content-base ./ --port 9966`):

webpack.config.js:

```
'use strict';

var ReactStylePlugin = require('react-style-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'sourcemap',
  entry: ['./js/main.js'],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: __dirname + '/assets',
    publicPath: __dirname + '/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: [
          ReactStylePlugin.loader(),
          'jsx-loader?harmony'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader')
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ReactStylePlugin('bundle.css'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        // To enable production mode:
        //NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    })
  ]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "reactTest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack",
    "web": "npm run watch &  webpack-dev-server --content-base ./ --port 9966"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.10.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.8",
    "jsx-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "react-style-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.10.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "webpack": "^1.8.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.8.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.13.1",
    "react-style": "^0.5.3"
  }
}
```

my directory structure is:

```
assets  
  bundle.css
  bundle.css.map    
  bundle.js 
  bundle.js.map 
js
  AppActions.js
  Profile.css.js
  ProfileList.js
  main.js
  AppConstants.js
  AppStore.js       
  Profile.js
  ResultPage.js     
package.json
index.html
node_modules
webpack.config.js
```

every file inside `assets` directory is generated by webpack

Answer (score 40, accepted):

you need to run webpack-dev-server with the --hot flag:

`webpack-dev-server --content-base ./ --port 9966 --hot`

Then you can access the hot-loading version localhost:9966/webpack-dev-server/

You don't need to run watch as well.

#### update:

This entry in your webpack config must change:

`entry: ['./js/main.js'],` --> `entry: ['webpack/hot/dev-server' , './js/main.js']`

Change your publicPath entry:

`publicPath: '/assets/'`

Comment: it was my first attemp.

if I put this on my webpack conf file:
"web":  "webpack-dev-server --content-base ./ --port 9966 --hot"

and I open my browser on http://localhost:9966/webpack-dev-server/,
if I change something, I see the phreses "App updated, recompiling.." and then  "App hot update.", but I can see my modification.
If I stop and restart the server, I still don't see the modification.
If I run "npm run watch" or "npm run build" and then I run the server, I see them correctly.

Comment: Ok let's see if we can figure out what you problem is, can you update your question to show me your directory structure - I want to check if your content-base setting is correct. It sounds like your bundle is not even getting loaded in webpack-dev-server.

Comment: Voted this up as the amended 'entry' line is what fixed things for me.Prior to that I had the same issue - the change was detected, the command line looked like it worked, the browser showed the 'app updated', but then no reload actually happened.

Comment: As soon as I update my main.js in entry, the page is being refreshed but the changes hasn't been occured on the page. Recompilation by `webpack-dev-server` doesn't affect, I stop server, run `webpack` again and then run `web-pack-server` as well and after that the change occurs. Is this normal or am I missing something?

Answer (score 43):

In order to get webpack to watch my file changes (Ubuntu 14.04), I had to increase the number of watchers (I had increased the number before, but it was still too low):

`echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`

Source in the official docs: https://webpack.github.io/docs/troubleshooting.html#not-enough-watchers

I first suspected the cause to be `fsevents` which doesn't work on Ubuntu, but this apparently wasn't the case.

Furthermore, because now the watching and re-compiling worked, but the automatic browser refresh part didn't work, I added the `--inline` param to the answer of @deowk which enables the "inline mode":
`webpack-dev-server --content-base ./ --port 9966 --hot --inline`

Quote from the official docs: "The easiest way to use Hot Module Replacement with the webpack-dev-server is to use the inline mode."
Source: https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#hot-module-replacement

Comment: This is correct answer for my case. I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and only this solution worked.

Comment: Increasing max user watches solved issue for me. Manjaro 18.1.0-rc8

Comment: Attached doc links are broken.

Answer (score 15):

@funkybunky identified the right problem but (IMHO) fixed it the wrong way.  At least in my case, webpack was trying to watch every file it used, including a deep chain of thousands of files of dependencies pulled from `npm`.  I added this to my config, [per the docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watchoptions):

```
devServer: {
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: /node_modules/
  }
}
```

Of course you legitimately could have thousands of files that might need to be watched, in which case go ahead and raise the limit, but you're probably better off ignoring vendor libraries that aren't likely to change.

Comment: did you mean to quote /node_modules/ ?

Comment: I did not.  If any path has "node_modules" anywhere in it, I definitely don't want to watch that path.  That's why I specified a regex instead.

Answer (score 5):

I'll put this here just in case it helps anyone. My problem was the same, but caused by inconsistent capitalization of directory names and webpack alias declaration.

I had a `WebGL` directory which i referenced in my aliases as `webgl`, and unfortunately this worked for the build, but didn't work for code watching.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was caused by an empty space in the directory name, by changing "Repository Name" by "RepositoryName", everything worked fine !

Answer (score 0):

Figured I'd post my solution as well.  I had the same problem getting Flutter apps to run on OS X due to my hard drive setup.

The gist is if your project folder is in a symlinked folder, detecting the file changes may not work on OS X.  Previously, we were on Webpack 3.X, I believe, and live reload/refresh worked fine in the original folder.  However, after upgrading to the latest Webpack (^5.75.0) and Webpack Dev Server (^4.11.1), the hot-reloading no longer worked for me.

My original project folder was:

```
/Users/blakemiller/h/somefolder/v2/my-widget
```

The "/h" there is a symlink to: /System/Volumes/Data/projects/home/web/

I'm not sure what happened when I upgraded OS X at some point, but the upgrade changed the folders in a way that I don't really understand.

Putting the folder here instead, fixed the issue for me (no symlink):

```
/Users/blakemiller/my-widget
```

I doubt this will work for many people, as my setup is probably pretty specific, but maybe it will help someone else save 5 hours down the road...